# Heptagon (septagon) diagonal intersection

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> Diagonals $TV$ and $UW$ of regular heptagon $TUVWXYZ$ meet at $A$. Prove that $TU+TA=TW$ (Source: AoPS ItG).

My observations:

- $TUVW$ is an isosceles trapezoid.
- Triangle $TUA$ is congruent to triangle $WVA$.

Answer (score 3):

A hint:

Choose $B$ on $WT$ such that $|WB|=|UT|$, and connect $A$ with $B$. Then find the angles of the triangles $TUA$, $ABW$, and $TAB$. They are all multiples of ${\pi\over7}$. (Note that two of these triangles are congruent.)

[image]